# Reordering a table based on non-numeric rownames

Tags: r

I'm trying to reorder the rows in a table based on the row name to a custom order, but my row names are characters rather than numbers.

I created a table of my data in R from a larger data frame using the `table` tool:

`data <- table(allcones$Type, allcones$Location)[,]`

This gives me a table that looks like this:

`>    Ada Alf   Lk  Lnd Myv Raud
  D    3   0   10    0  59    0
  H 3777   0    0    0   8    0
  L   11   0   34    4  34    5
  P    0   0    0    0 187    0
  S  585   0 1880    0 460  109
  T  100   0    0    0 233    0
  U  234 517  401 4057   9    0`

The row names (D, H, L...) are currently ordered alphabetically, which I think is the default in R. However, they each reflect a different class of data so I want to put them into a custom order.

I tried using 
`reorder(row.names(data), new.order=c('L', 'D', 'S', 'T', 'H', 'P', 'U'))` based on other questions on this site, but this doesn't work. It seems that `row.names(data)` is not a valid argument in the `reorder` function.

I don't want to create a new column to force the order because I'm using this data to make a stacked barplot of the table (using `barplot(data, ...)`) and I wouldn't know how to get rid of the extra column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best solution but you could always use dplyr if the row order was based on one of the column names.

eg if you wanted them sorted by the 'Myv' order, you could use -

```
library('dplyr')
dataa <- arrange(data, Myv)
```

Answer (score 1):

`table()` respects the ordering of the levels of the factors wither passed in as arguments or those arguments coerced to factors (in which case the default ordering of levels will be produced).

So, instead of

```
df <- data.frame(f1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 f2 = sample(letters[23:26], 1000, replace = TRUE))
with(df, table(f1, f2))
```

which gives

```
> with(df, table(f1, f2))
   f2
f1   w  x  y  z
  A 48 41 44 63
  B 35 50 35 49
  C 52 79 48 52
  D 49 51 50 55
  E 46 45 60 48
```

set the `levels` of the factor arguments explicitly to the ordering you want. For example here I just reverse the ordering but you could specify it explicitly:

```
df2 <- transform(df, f1 = factor(f1, levels = LETTERS[5:1]),
                     f2 = factor(f2, levels = letters[26:23]))
with(df2, table(f1, f2))
```

which gives

```
> with(df2, table(f1, f2))
   f2
f1   z  y  x  w
  E 48 60 45 46
  D 55 50 51 49
  C 52 48 79 52
  B 49 35 50 35
  A 63 44 41 48
```

In your specific example I would do

```
allcones <- transform(allcones,
                      Type = factor(Type, levels = c("L","D","S","T","H","P", "U"))
with(allcones, table(Type, Location))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the help file, `reorder` is used to reorder factor levels. Somewhat confusingly, `order` is used (among other things) to order rows of data.frames.

It is possible to use the `factor` function along with `order` to achieve your desired result.

```
dfMyOrder <- df[order(factor(row.names(df), levels=c('L', 'D', 'S', 'T', 'H', 'P', 'U'))),]
```

which returns

```
dfMyOrder

   Ada Alf   Lk  Lnd Myv Raud
L   11   0   34    4  34    5
D    3   0   10    0  59    0
S  585   0 1880    0 460  109
T  100   0    0    0 233    0
H 3777   0    0    0   8    0
P    0   0    0    0 187    0
U  234 517  401 4057   9    0
```

This will work for table objects as well as data.frames, but as @gavin-simpson discusses in his post, it would be preferable to perform the ordering prior to calculating the table.

Comment: Note that `data` in the OP's example is an object of class `"table"` (which is really a matrix with some extra stuff on it) not a data frame.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering from your row names is indeed alphabetical and it comes from the fact that your variable `Type` is a factor (or is being coerced into it). You can re-order the levels of your factors before using `table`.

Here is an example using the `warpbreaks` dataset that comes with R:

```
w <- warpbreaks
table(w$tension, w$wool)
# The default order here is L, M, H (not alphabetical) 
#    A B
#  L 9 9
#  M 9 9
#  H 9 9
## let's redefine the order:
w$tension <- factor(w$tension, levels = c("H", "M", "L"))
table(w$tension, w$wool)
#    A B
#  H 9 9
#  M 9 9
#  L 9 9
```